# Trouble installing TensorFlow

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, pip

When trying to install [`tensorflow-gpu`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tensorflow-gpu) with `pip3 install tensorflow-gpu` I get the following error message:

```
Collecting tensorflow-gpu
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-gpu (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow-gpu
```

I have installed the [NVIDIA CUDA drivers](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/). I have restarted my system. I reinstalled python with `python-3.7.0a2-amd64-webinstall.exe`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Python 3.5.x fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
```

Comment: Are you sure that tensorflow supports python 3.7?